# Embed Facebook videos are played low quality on smartphone

Tags: html, wordpress, facebook, iframe

I have an issue with a video I embedded on a page of our website. When it is viewed from a desktop computer everything is fine, and it plays in HD.

However, on a mobile device, the video goes full screen in really low quality.

I tried many answers around, changing iframe width and height, adding `?vq=hd720` (which I read is deprecated) etc. but cannot find a solution.

What am I missing?

Link of the webpage: https://www.coachweero.it/inizia-gratis-ableton-accelerator/lezione-1/

Comment: There are no plugin parameters for this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How are you adding the video to your site? If you are adding it in your code, then please include the code you are using so we can help. If you are using a plugin or adding it directly into the page editor, then please note that Stack Overflow is a site for programming-related questions and in that case your question is off topic for this site.

Comment: @FluffyKitten where do you want me to add the iframe code? Here or editing the question?

<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FCoachWeero%2Fvideos%2F582827245698274%2F&show_text=0&width=560" width="560" height="320" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>

Comment: You should edit your question (not comments - they are not designed for code) to include whatever information is required so that we can recreate the problem to see what is happening. Please see how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - this is what questions should include.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I'm using:

`<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FCoachWeero%2Fvideos%2F582827245698274%2F&show_text=0&width=560" width="560" height="320" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>`